# Add-on compatibility in TorBrowser

Tags: firefox, selenium-webdriver, firefox-addon, xpi, tor-browser-bundle

I have a FireFox add-on which installs successfully with latest Firefox ESR (currently 24.6.0), but returns this error when attempting to install on the latest Tor Browser Bundle.

> My Test WebDriver could not be installed because it is not compatible with TorBrowser 24.6.0.

[image: Tor Browser Version]

**Why does Tor Browser say this is not compatible, but Firefox 24.6.0 does? And how can my .xpi be modified to make it work?**

Here is my `install.rdf`:

```
<?xml version="1.0"?>
<RDF xmlns="http://www.w3.org/1999/02/22-rdf-syntax-ns#" xmlns:em="http://www.mozilla.org/2004/em-rdf#">

    <Description about="urn:mozilla:install-manifest">
        <em:id>test@example.com</em:id>
        <em:version>2.42.0</em:version>
        <em:name>My Test WebDriver</em:name>
        <em:description>WebDriver implementation for Firefox</em:description>
        <em:creator>Simon Stewart</em:creator>
        <em:unpack>true</em:unpack>

        <!-- Firefox -->
        <em:targetApplication>
            <Description>
                <em:id>{ec8030f7-c20a-464f-9b0e-13a3a9e97384}</em:id>
                <em:minVersion>17.0</em:minVersion>
                <em:maxVersion>10000.0</em:maxVersion>
            </Description>
        </em:targetApplication>

        <!-- Platforms where we're not compiling the native events -->
        <em:targetPlatform>Darwin</em:targetPlatform>
        <em:targetPlatform>SunOS</em:targetPlatform>
        <em:targetPlatform>FreeBSD</em:targetPlatform>

        <!-- Platforms where we are -->
        <em:targetPlatform>WINNT_x86-msvc</em:targetPlatform>
        <em:targetPlatform>Linux</em:targetPlatform>
    </Description>

</RDF>
```

I'm attempting to get Selenium WebDriver to work with the [Tor Browser Bundle](https://www.torproject.org/projects/torbrowser.html.en) using a manual *.xpi*.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The problem here is actually your `targetPlatforms`. The TorBrowser is compiled differently to enable allow them to do deterministic builds. In particular the Tor Browser is compiled by some mingw-gcc while the official Firefox is compiled by a MSVC compiler.

Remember that [`targetPlatform`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/Add-ons/Install_Manifests#targetPlatform) is:

> A string specifying a platform that the add-on supports. It contains either the value of OS_TARGET alone or combined with TARGET_XPCOM_ABI, separated by an underscore (_).

In the TorBrowser, `OS_TARGET` still is `WINNT`, but `XPCOMABI` is `x86-gcc3` apparantly. So your `targetPlatform` of `WINNT_x86-msvc` does not match the expected `WINNT_x86-gcc3`.

BTW: You can get `OS_TARGET` and `XPCOMABI` from a running browser instance, e.g. by opening a web console on an `about:newtab` tab and executing:
﻿

```
Services.appinfo.OS
// and
Services.appinfo.XPCOMABI
```

So the first order of business would be trying to add `WINNT_x86-gcc3` to your `targetPlatform`s.

As you apparently have binary components this may or may not work... not sure if MSVC compiled "glue" is compatible to a gcc compiled one, so your binary components may still fail to load.
You might then have to recompile your component for the different target using the appropriate compiler (mingw-gcc something; see the TOR deterministic build docs about this), or, and this might be better in the long run anyway, switch over to js-ctypes and regular C API/ABI libraries if possible.

Comment: This worked to get it installed. I added `WINNT_x86-gcc3` as a target platform, and duplicated the folder under `/platforms/WINNT_x86-msvc`. Haven't been able to test if the `.dll`s in the folder still work as intended.